# Why I can not get data from web service, I get feed back"List does not exist."

Tags: ios, web-services, soap, asihttprequest

Below is the code to request web service, I get the feed back @"List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user."

```
NSString *soapMessage = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><GetList xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\"><listName>Contact</listName></GetList></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

NSString * wsURL = @"http://192.168.11.133/Jason/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";

NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",wsURL]];
ASIHTTPRequest * theRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

[theRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"];
[theRequest addRequestHeader:@"SOAPAction" value:@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetList"];
[theRequest setUsername:@"username"];
[theRequest setPassword:@"password"];
 [theRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Length" value:msgLength];
 [theRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
 [theRequest appendPostData:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

 [theRequest setDefaultResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[theRequest setTimeOutSeconds:20];
[theRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(onRequestFail:)];
[theRequest startSynchronous];
```

The webservice is from sharepoint. 
I feel my code is correct. Can anyone give some advice? Thanks.

Comment: Your code look ok. The error you are getting back is a server error. There might be an error with the sever. Also I should move to AFNetworking because ASIHTTPRequest is no longer under development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be SharePoint issue.
Using IP directly will cause some issues. 
I solve the problem by mapping the host name.

Answer (score 1):

offtopic:

[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) is not longer supported and for POST Request the is a class `ASIFormDataRequest`

> Please note that I am no longer working on this library - you may want to consider using something else for new projects. :)

You could you an alternative like:

- [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) (my favorite choice)
- [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit)